# Get this error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near “ ”: syntax error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hey guys I hope you can help me out here

I get this error but can't find how to solve the problem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sergej.myapplication4/com.sergej.slidnerd_kopie.training.MeinePlaene_main}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SETSworkout": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE SETSworkout(name TEXT)
```

That is the my Create Table

```
public class WorkoutDataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "dmworkouts.db";
    public static final String WORKOUT_TABLE_NAME = "workouts";

    public static final String SETS_TABLE_NAME = "workouts";
    public static final String SESSIONS_TABLE_NAME = "sessions";
    public static final String CREATE_WORKOUT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + WORKOUT_TABLE_NAME +
            " ( name TEXT )";
    public static final String CREATE_SETS_TABLE ="CREATE SETS"+SETS_TABLE_NAME+"(name TEXT)";
    public static final String CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + SESSIONS_TABLE_NAME +
            " ( time INTEGER, workoutid  INTEGER, type INTEGER)";


    public WorkoutDataHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_WORKOUT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SETS_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE);
    }


}
```

I think the problem is somewhere at `CREATE_WORKOUT_TABLE` but I tried to solve it but I did not make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space when concatenating the strings :

```
"CREATE SETS"+SETS_TABLE_NAME+"(name TEXT)"
```

should be:

```
"CREATE SETS "+SETS_TABLE_NAME+"(name TEXT)"
```

hence the given error. You can see in the error messages that the word `SET` is not seperated from the table name making it a one word which makes the statement invalid.

Comment: I am not familiar with the SETS keyword and couldn't find it also on google. Where is it from ? did you mean TABLE instead?